# K6 user and batch processing concept

Tags: load-testing, k6

How does k6 interpret the following case:
I have two requests which I run in parallel with batch() and command line switch -u 4, that is 4 users.
In that case is k6 running the 2 requests per user? that is 2x4 = 8 times ?
And is that one user after the other in sequential order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first assumption is correct, k6 will make 8 requests, but this will happen concurrently, not sequentially, since VUs are also run in [parallel](https://k6.io/docs/getting-started/running-k6#adding-more-vus).

Note that it would be 8 requests if you limited the number of total iterations with `-i 4`, otherwise if you specified a `--duration` it would run as many iterations, and thus requests, as possible.

Consider posting on the [k6 community forum](https://community.k6.io/) if you need further help. (Disclaimer: I'm a k6 maintainer.)